# CRM 2011 Silverlight Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, stored-procedures, dynamics-crm-2011

Are there any ways to call the `Stored Procedure` that is stored in the `SQL Server` of `CRM 2011`?

I want to make a `Silverlight` app that will be used by `CRM 2011` and it will requires data that use the `Stored Procedure` (this is because of the complexity of the query - dynamic sql, temp table, etc)

Comment: I would imagine you would call it like you would call any other stored procedure in a SQL Server database, assuming you have security rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use WCF services with ado.net.

following link can help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37393/4-Simple-Steps-to-Consume-WCF-Service-using-Silver